# How to create the letter 'A' without the central bar and apply a gradient overlay in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, gradient, lettering

I want to know how the A in this logo can be created in Photoshop and how the effects are applied. I found the font and other things.

[image: BASIC text logo]

I am not able to create the character `A` without the central bar in Photoshop.

**How can I create the character 'A', and apply a gradient overlay, just like the one in the picture?**

Comment: I'm not sure if you're having trouble creating the shape of the A or if you need help with the gradient effect, or both. Could you clarify and let us know what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 7):

- Type a V
- Rotate it 180°
- Apply a gradient overlay.

[image: v]

Comment: Brainfart! Totally missed the upside down v lol. That's why they pay you the big bucks! ;)

Comment: It's not an upside down V, it's a Λ! :)

Comment: That sample.. is an upside down V. :)

Comment: Hi Scott, that is really great...but I want to know how to create this whole logo. I am new to photoshop. so, I don't have any idea how to edit text individually once I tried to edit V it rotates all the text. Please help.

Comment: Hi Scott, Please tell me how to do this ? I have written "BASIC" in Photoshop using text too. Now I have written "V" but once I try to rotate the V photoshop rotate the whole "Basic" to 180 degree. Please let me know how can I rotate just V from the word.

Comment: Just write B, then A(V), and then SIC (you will create 3 blocks of text), now you can grab letter A(V) alone and rotate it.

Comment: how to apply inner glow on just one letter in a text?

Answer (score -5):

You have to do everything individually, if you have a problem with this, I suggest you make a font in illustrator or something :)

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for your answer. I've downvoted, since it doesn't really answer the question in any meaningful way. Could you elaborate or clarify what you're saying?